# Concise way of defining ES6 symbols?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, symbols

If I want to define multiple symbols in a row, the syntax is a little verbose:

```
const a = Symbol('a'),
    b = Symbol('b'),
    c = Symbol('c');
```

I came up with a slightly more concise way to do it:

```
const [a, b, c] = ['a','b','c'].map(key => Symbol(key))
```

Is that the most concise way possible, or is there some dedicated syntax for declaring multiple symbols that I'm unaware of?

P.S. 'a' 'b' and 'c' are just arbitrary examples of course. I realize that one could get clever with this particular example ;)

Comment: Destructuring seems to be the most concise way to achieve this. I don't know if you can beat destructuring though

Comment: not sure if that is valid, but maybe `s=Symbol, a=s('a'), b=s('b'), c=s('c')`

Comment: @Slai - you should test it - I wouldn't call that more concise, it's just shorter :p

Comment: For the record, `s = Symbol` does work, thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be as concise as

```
const [a, b, c] = ['a','b','c'].map(Symbol);
```

There's no way to skip *abc* tautology here because variable names should be explicitly written, as well as symbol description.

Symbol descriptions are helpful for debugging. If they can be omitted (not recommended), it becomes

```
const [a, b, c] = [,,].map(Symbol);
```

for fixed amount of variables. And

```
const [a, b, c, d /*, ... */] = function* () { for(;;) yield Symbol() }();
```

for unlimited amount of variables.

Answer (score 2):

There's a fun part of FP that you might be missing out on, which is that in a pure system, you can always replace an anonymous function with a named reference which is returned (and more generally, you can always replace a function with the value it would have returned), assuming that the function you're replacing and the function you're replacing it with take the same number of arguments.

```
const [a, b, c] = ["a", "b", "c"].map(Symbol);
```

Should work just fine, as long as you keep in mind that you can cause accidents here, by passing in functions that expect more than 1 argument.

Sure, not much more terse than what you already had.  ...but still more than none.

Comment: Good point. I actually often just pass in the function itself (as you suggested) rather than creating a new anonymous function, but it didn't occur to me in this particular case - thanks for pointing it out :)

Answer (score 1):

One option, if you don't mind using ES6-only features that can't be polyfilled, is to use a `Proxy` that returns a symbol for each property access. You could make a helper module file like

```
module.exports = function autoSymbols() {
  return new Proxy({}, {
    get(target, name, receiver){
      return Symbol(name);
    },
  });
}
```

then do

```
const {a, b, c} = require('./auto-symbols');
```

though personally I think enumerating the `Symbol` instances manually is more easily maintained.

Comment: Why a proxy? It's a perfect use case for iterable.

Comment: This gives them names based on the properties. I totally agree that an iterable is another good solution though.

Comment: That's a good point. I guess this should be stated in the answer. Generally symbol debuggability shouldn't be sacrificed for code golf.

Comment: +1. This is very clever, thank you :) It's a bit convoluted, so I accepted estus's answer, but I might still experiment with it... When you say that manually enumerating the symbols would be more easily maintained, are you just saying the same thing - that it's more easily readable - or is there more to it?

Comment: Oh by enumerating them I meant listing them manually like you did in your question because I see your "little verbose" example as much more maintainable, and you only have to write it once anyway.